# Comparing char array[ ] with char *array[ ]?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Sorry if the terminology in the title is incorrect but basically I want to compare a char array with a char * array that contains string literals.
Basically I have an array:

```
char temp[6];
cin.get();
cout << "Enter: ";
cin.getline(temp,6);
```

And:

```
char *compare[10] = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};
```

How do I go about comparing the string entered by the user into "temp" with the "compare" array elements. Example if user enters: " -... " it compares the string entered with every single element of "compare" and check if it matches? 
I have tried doing comparisons but it always gives me an error saying " ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|"

Comment: If you're using C++, use `std::string`. What you're using is a C-ism and not considered C++.

Comment: What exactly have you "tried"?

Comment: @tambre The code posted is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: Please get a good book.  This will be covered.  `std::string temp; std::getline(std::cin, temp); static const std:string compare[] = { /* initialize */ }; bool found = false; for (const auto& s : compare) { if (s == temp) { found == true; break;} }`

Comment: @NeilButterworth: It *is*, but using char arrays is making life hard for the OP

Comment: @NeilButterworth I wasn't saying it wasn't valid. Except it smells of someone coming from C. Basically they need a modern C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the facilities of the STL wherever applicable always. So that you can change this hullabaloo:

> ```
> char temp[6];
> cin.get();
> cout << "Enter: ";
> cin.getline(temp,6);
>
> char *compare[10] = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};
> ```

to:

```
std::string temp;
std::cout << "Enter: ";
std::getline(std::cin, temp);

std::vector<std::string> compare = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};
```

Now to find whether the entered string matches:

```
auto iter = std::find(compare.begin(), compare.end(), temp);
if(iter != compare.end(){
     // You have a match!
}
```

---

A full example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

    std::string temp;
    std::cout << "Enter: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);

    std::vector<std::string> compare = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};

    auto iter = std::find(compare.begin(), compare.end(), temp);
    if(iter != compare.end(){
         //To obtain index from an iterator
         auto index = std::distance(iter, compare.end());

         std::cout << "We found a match at: " << index << '\n';
    }

}
```

If you have lots of questions about the code above, you probably want to check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `const auto iter` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use STL feature as much as possible. In your current scenario try using `std::string` instead of `char*` and `std::vector` instead of `char* arr`.

You can replace your existing code

```
char temp[6];
cin.get();
cout << "Enter: ";
cin.getline(temp,6);

char *compare[10] = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};
```

By this

```
std::string temp;
std::cout << "Enter: ";
std::getline(std::cin, temp);

std::vector<std::string> compare = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. "};
```

Now you can iterator over this compare vector like

```
for(const auto& iter : compare) {
    // Do the comparison to check whether it's a match or not.
}
```

Comment: The name of your loop variable in the for loop is *very* misleading.  It is *not* an iterator, it is an element of the array.